# Invoice management gem for Rails 3.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am looking for an invoice management gem to use with my Rails application. I tried the Ruby Invoicing Framework (http://ept.github.com/invoicing/) but it doesn't seem to work with Rails 3.

Are there any other invoice management gems available for Rails 3.x ?

Answer (score 2):

Invoices are complex and have a lot of business rules that go with them -- along with processes such as sending, tracking, sending reminders, etc. Instead of looking for a gem, I'd recommend considering using an API from an existing application provider. There are a few good ones around you could choose from.

Here are three:

Freshbooks Invoice API:  http://developers.freshbooks.com/docs/invoices/

ZOHO Invoice API:        http://www.zoho.com/invoice/api/index.html

Harvest Invoice API:   http://www.getharvest.com/api/invoices

These services have fully-featured invoice systems that would probably take you less time to get up and running than if you could find a gem to help you build your own.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [list](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=invoice) where you can find many alternatives to invoicing.

Answer (score -1):

There are many invoicing apps available online but I think you should go with the one that presently I am using because it is available free online and is very simple, easy and feature rich tool for invoicing.Check the website http://www.nutcache.com.